# Unable to login after deleting the "libxml" package in Synaptic

Tags: login, synaptic, libxml

When I deleted the `libxml` in Synaptic, the Synaptic removed my ubuntu system and I cannot login! so I need reinstall the ubuntu system! Can you help me find a better solution than having to reinstall Ubuntu?

another issue is: my benq scanner 5560 cannot be detected and NO backend from the sane project.

Comment: Two separate questions, so, please post two different questions. (Edit this one to remove the scanner part of the question and post a new scanner question)

Answer (score 2):

You can reinstall all packages from the recovery mode.

When booting the computer, you will see a list of all installed operating systems (GRUB). If not, press the left shift during boot.
Select the Ubuntu Recovery mode, and in the next screen choose "netroot".
There, enter the following command, which will install all packages that come with a default Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```